# Create a column df[New_column] and write Yes/No based on other multiple column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Condition to apply :

I have a df and i want to fill with yes/no based on the below condition :

```
If column1 >= 20 and column2 >= 4 and column3 >= 30 then write Yes else write No
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKmIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), as follows:

```
df['New_column'] = np.where((df['column1'] >= 20) & (df['column2'] >= 4) & (df['column3'] >= 30), 'Yes', 'No')
```